# Synchronize the value of the text field with tooltip content in Vuetify

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<v-col class="d-flex align-center">
   <v-tooltip bottom>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
         <v-text-field
            v-on="on"
            :value="info.payeeNo"
            dense
            label="Another payer"/>
      </template>
      <span>{{info.payeeNo}}</span>
   </v-tooltip>
</v-col>
```

I would like the tooltip to be the same as the value of the text field.
I have tried using this code and this.info.payeeNo but it all shows a blank field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `v-model` instead of `:value` to make two-way binding :

```
<v-col class="d-flex align-center">
   <v-tooltip bottom>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
         <v-text-field
            v-on="on"
            v-model="info.payeeNo"
            dense
            label="Another payer"/>
      </template>
      <span>{{info.payeeNo}}</span>
   </v-tooltip>
</v-col>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/WNxWYRY)**